# Configuring AWS OpenSearch Rollover Index Based on Data Size from Different Sources

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, nosql, opensearch

I am currently working on configuring AWS OpenSearch to handle indexes based on the size of data from different sources. Specifically, I have multiple sources such as mobile and website, each providing varying amounts of data. For example, data from the website is relatively small (less than 100 records), while data from the mobile application is larger (around 1000 records).

I am attempting to implement a solution using the rollover index feature in AWS OpenSearch. I have created a policy, alias, and template for my index. Below is the policy configuration:

```
{
"id": "urm-event-pulse",
"seqNo": 519,
"primaryTerm": 1,
"policy": {
    "policy_id": "urm-event-pulse",
    "description": "new policy for urm event",
    "last_updated_time": 1701606099266,
    "schema_version": 19,
    "error_notification": null,
    "default_state": "urm-event-state",
    "states": [
        {
            "name": "urm-event-state",
            "actions": [
                {
                    "retry": {
                        "count": 3,
                        "backoff": "exponential",
                        "delay": "1m"
                    },
                    "rollover": {
                        "min_size": "2mb",
                        "copy_alias": false
                    }
                }
            ],
            "transitions": []
        }
    ],
    "ism_template": [
        {
            "index_patterns": [
                "urm-event"
            ],
            "priority": 1,
            "last_updated_time": 1701590727665
        }
    ]
}
```

Despite following the instructions I found, I am facing issues, and the expected behavior is not being achieved. I suspect there might be a mistake in my configuration. Can someone please review the provided policy and suggest any corrections or additional steps I should take to achieve the desired result?

Thank you for your assistance.